# How to bridge Asus router over wired connection to Linksys router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have an [Asus RT-AC68R](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTAC68R/) router that is itself plugged into an old Linksys WRT54G that is then plugged into the cable modem.  We have two routers to get coverage across the house with a wired connection between the Linksys at the modem and the Asus at the other end of the house.  Using a MacBook Pro laptop computer all seems to be fine when connecting wirelessly to the Asus, however, when the Sony Blu-Ray player tries to connect it fails over the Asus wireless with an indication that the wireless connection is OK but the Internet access failed.  I'm thinking that perhaps the router plugged into another router is the issue and wonder if there is a bridge mode where the Asus uses the other router that it is plugged into to assign IP addresses etc and the Asus is just a wireless access point that goes into a wired connection at the other router.  The Asus does have a bridge mode, but that appears to be for repeating a wireless connection.  Please suggest how I might adjust things to work properly.  I don't see any Access Point (AP) mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suspect going the other way makes sense, the ASUS is significantly more powerful, and you can set the ddwrt on forwarding mode (i've done this with another asus router and a DD-WRT WRT54GL). If you do want to keep this topology There's a few things you want to check

1. the asus is set to AP, not router mode.  AP is found in the Administration tab, under Operation Mode.
2. You have your connection set to allow legacy connections and have it set to enable 20mhz bands, rather than force 40 or 80 mhz bands
3. That other devices can connect.

Comment: Cable modem is at other end of house, so for now Linksys will be first.